# How to get nested flexbox to work with image

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

So my use case is pretty simple. I have an image and a div with text inside.

The div has flex set to the column.

I want to get flex set to row for the text + image so that they are side by side.

While the text flexbox is congruent, currently the image displays above the text. What is wrong with my code here?

```css
.promptParent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.prompt {
  position: absolute;
  width: 540px;
  height: 180px;
  left: 450px;
  top: 67px;
  font-family: Coiny;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="promptParent">
  <div class="prompt">
    <h1>Sketch</h1>
    <h2>90% Dog</h2>
    <h2>10% Human</h2>
  </div>
  <a href="https://www.google.com">
    <img src="/" alt="Refresh Button for Prompt" />
  </a>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please share a codepen?

Comment: Assuming you are using a `React` framework of some sort, I changed `className` to `class` so that you have a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using some sort of React framework, I changed `className` to `class`.

So the problem is actually because of the absolute positioning (has nothing to do with `z-index`). Absolute positioning with position values set will have no regard for flex, as the browser is instructing them to retain this position absolutely.

Now it seems you have the absolute positioning because you want the elements in `prompt` to be centered on the page vertically and horizontally. There are ways to do this using `transform`, but there is an easier way using the `body` element. Just simply add `min-height: 100vh;` with `display: flex;`, then instruct the browser to position it in the center with `justify-content: center;` ~ center of the page.

Moving on to the flex, now that your absolute positioning is gone and you remove the fixed height and width on `prompt` you can use `align-items: center;` to position them inline, or whatever align you desire. Then I just used `gap` to space them out.

Feel free to adjust as necessary. See the snippet below or try out the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/yestk2oj/11/).

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.promptParent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 3em;
}

.prompt {
  font-family: Coiny;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="promptParent">
    <a href="https://www.google.com">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="Refresh Button for Prompt" />
    </a>
    <div class="prompt">
      <h1>Sketch</h1>
      <h2>90% Dog</h2>
      <h2>10% Human</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the z-index property (https://idg.net.ua/blog/uchebnik-css/razmetka-css/z-index)

Comment: Please add this answer as a comment ! or explain by yourself